# mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.1 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: mysql, debian, apt, debian-squeeze

I want to install MySQL on Squeeze (Debian), but I get this error message from apt:

```
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.1 but it is not going to be installed
```

I have tried to use a different source, but the issue persists.

**source.list:**

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main
```

I guess it's a dependency problem but I don't know which repositories are fine.

```
root@10909-05:/archiv# apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.1 : Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.73-1) but it is not going to be installed <br>
                    Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

**EDIT:** I upgraded to wheezy, now I can install mysql-server.

Comment: Please provide your sources.list file. Have you tried `apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: source.list: deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main  apt-get -f install: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Add those repos to your source.list file:   `deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free`
# Stable Sources
`deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free`  Then run `apt-get update` and try to install the package.

Comment: Same result: mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.1 but it is not going to be installed

Comment: When adding extra information, please edit the question and add it there with proper formatting. What does `apt-get install mysql-server-5.1` tell you?

Comment: This is seems to be a problem with your sources. Can you send the output of: `uname -a` and `cat /etc/debian-version`, `apt-cache policy mysql-server` also `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`